# Hibernate update is not working

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

my hibernate saveOrUpdate method is not working.
i did not want to use load() or get(). Is it possible to update the record.
my update method in dao layer. i am calling it from main method. It does not throws any exceptions

```
 public String updateEmp(EmployeeBean empBean) {
    Session session = null;
    try {
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        if (null != session) {
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.saveOrUpdate(empBean);
            System.out.println("Updated");
        } 

    } catch (Exception e) {
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
       e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            session.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            session = null;
        }
    }
    return "updated";
}
```

My main method is

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee dao = new Employee();
        EmployeeBean empBean = new EmployeeBean();
        empBean.setEmpid("123"); //primary key in databse
        empBean.setFirstname("rahul");
        empBean.setLastname("sharma");
        dao.updateEmp(empBean);
    }
```

thanx in advance

Comment: can we see your table data please

Comment: And how does it "not work"? What happens if you add e.printStackTrace() in the last catch block, instead of ignoring the exception?

Comment: In databse empId=123(it is primary key) already exist. i just want to update the firstName and lastName.and other column in Db table are phnNumber, email, etc...

Comment: in finally catch e.printStacktrace() print following  org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value: EmployeeBean.email

Comment: @javababa: so now you have your answer: the email can't be null.

Answer (score 3):

Set the show_sql property to true to see if there are some sql printed.

If not , your session may be null so the code for updating wasn't run at all.

print the exception below may be you will see...

```
  try {
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        session = null;
    }
```

Check your session or try to use getCurrentSession() instead.

Comment: No the close call must occur in the finally block. try { something(); commit();} catch (e) { rollback();} finally { close(); } setting the session to null is just useless

Comment: @Gab  I copied the code from the question to remind the author to get the `e` printed.

Answer (score 0):

The way you commit a transaction is not in a proper way. 
It prefers to commit in try block.When an exception happen in try block{}, the transaction will be rollback in catch block.Then another exception will happen in finnaly block to commit().

Answer (score 0):

after little research i found the answer.
 i need to change in EmployeeBean.hbm.xml

```
<property name="email" type="string">
  <column name="EMAIL" length="60" not-null="true">
  </column>
</property>
```

not-null="true"> replace with not-null="false">